# Selecting Data from Last Week in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, format, dataframe

I have a large database and I am looking to read only the last week for my python code.

My first problem is that the column with the received date and time is not in the format for datetime in pandas. My input (Column 15) looks like this:

```
recvd_dttm
1/1/2015 5:18:32 AM
1/1/2015 6:48:23 AM
1/1/2015 13:49:12 PM
```

From the Time Series / Date functionality in the pandas library I am looking at basing my code off of the "Week()" function shown in the example below:

```
In [87]: d
Out[87]: datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 18, 9, 0)

In [88]: d - Week()
Out[88]: Timestamp('2008-08-11 09:00:00')
```

I have tried ordering the date this way:

```
df =pd.read_csv('MYDATA.csv')
orderdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['recvd_dttm'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y %m %d')
```

however I am getting this error

```
TypeError: must be string, not Series
```

Does anyone know a simpler way to do this, or how to fix this error?

Edit: The dates are not necessarily in order. AND sometimes there is a faulty error in the database like a date that is 9/03/2015 (in the future) someone mistyped. I need to be able to ignore those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

# convert strings to datetimes
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

# get first and last datetime for final week of data
range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - dt.timedelta(days=7)

# take slice with final week of data
sliced_df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

Comment: Quick add-on question, I have a date in the future (written in by accident, I'm sure) that is screwing with my code. How do I ignore dates not in the range?

Comment: Instead of doing `.max()` you could enter the maximum datetime manually.

Comment: The code will be auto-updating every few minutes so manual isn't really an option.

Comment: Ah, since it's in the future you could first select all rows not in the future -- using `dt.datetime.now()` -- and then do the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over the dates to convert by making a list comprehension

```
orderdate = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ttm, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y %m %d') for ttm in list(df['recvd_dttm'])]
```

Comment: ah hah! I think this is working. The only problem is what to do with the time variable. I get "ValueError: unconverted data remains:  5:18" I don't really care about the time, I care more about reading the last week of data.