# Get values with specific week number - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, week-number

I have a df with a significant amount of values. I would like to select all values occured the last 5 weeks of my set. I have tried with timedelta. I am aware that my code is not running but it is just to give you an idea at what direction I am aiming. I also tried with nlargest but it only gives me 5 values of the prior week.

```
gdf_hpo['weeknumber']=gdf_hpo[DATE].dt.week
gdf_hpo_2 = gdf_hpo.copy(deep=True)

get_last_week=gdf_hpo_2['weeknumber'].max()
week_prior_5=gdf_hpo_2['weeknumber'].max() - timedelta(weeks=5)
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use slicing, should work. And as ijdnam_alim mentioned, use days.

```
week_prior_5=gdf_hpo_2['weeknumber'].max() - timedelta(days=35)

df_5weeks = gdf_hpo_2[(gdf_hpo_2.weeknumber <= gdf_hpo_2.weeknumber.max()) \
                       and (gdf_hpo_2.weeknumber > week_prior_5)]
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I have just adjusted to my situation and it perfectly works !

Comment: No worries, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try not `weeks = 5`, but transform weeks into days, so it will be
`days = 35`. I saw the similar question on the Stackoverflow, maybe it will help to solve your issue: [Selecting Data from Last Week in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984920/selecting-data-from-last-week-in-python).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be not a good idea to use only week number, because it also depends on a year. I recommend you use this:

```
cut_off_date = gdf_hpo['DATE'].max() - timedelta(weeks=5)
cut_off_dataset = gdf_hpo[gdf_hpo['DATE']>=cut_off_date]
```

Also your mistake was that you tried to use week number (which is actually only a number) and timedelta. Timedelta works with dates. So you should had subtracted not a timedelta, but just a number 5. And then filter by week number. However, as I said, it's better to use dates, not only week numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I get your point and it perfectly works. I changed weeks=5 with days=35 to not depend on the year !

Comment: @ThomasRivière day number also depends on the year, it's better to use the whole date